# Cannot load module 'UIKit' as 'UIKit'

Tags: ios, swift

Currently trying to open an app created in Swift 3, Xcode 8.1. I have done tonnes of research, deleting derived data and cleaning the entire project over and over. I have updated Xcode to its newest version, as well as syntax. MapKit may be interfering but I doubt it. It's a really small project with only 2 VC's. I directly downloaded the project from a website (https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-05-05-getting-started-ios-location-tracking-and-streaming-w-swift-programming-language/) and after installing the pods required I still get the error. I am also opening the workspace, not just the project itself. If there is any more information you require, let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: After successfully installing pod, you need to open projectName.xcworkspace file not projectName.xcodeproj. make sure you opened correct one.

Comment: I am opening the workspace. If you want to take a look at it any closer you can download the project here: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-05-05-getting-started-ios-location-tracking-and-streaming-w-swift-programming-language/ - I am not sure why it is not working as it is made to be suitable for downloaders. All pods have been installed properly as well.

Comment: @EricAya The download comes with 4 folders and inside each of them is a project with a workspace. I'm really just trying to use this concept of location tracking realtime for my own idea I have, and I thought pubnub's resources would be fairly easy to use.

Comment: @EricAya I know what you mean now, and the workspace was created when I installed the pods required. I don't see what the problem should be?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it was spelled incorrectly?

I wrote `UIkit` instead of `UIKit` and got this error:

[image]